# Wrong floating images

Tags: html, css, floating

I am trying to play with hover effects but I got a problem. I am trying to put 6 images next to each other into two columns. But it is not displayed correctly. I want them to be displayed side by side but the only first two are displayed like that. The other four are below each other. Could you help me, please? :)

```css
body {
 color: #333;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.column {
 margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 padding: 0;
}
.column:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.column::after {
 content: "";
 /*clear: both;*/
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}
.column div {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 375px;
 height: 225px;
 margin: 0 0 0 25px;
 padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.column div span {
  float: left;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -20px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline;
 width: 375px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #444;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
}
figure {
 width: 400px;
 height: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
}
figure:hover+span {
 bottom: -36px;
 opacity: 1;
}

/* Shine */
.hover14 figure {
 position: relative;
}
.hover14 figure::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -75%;
 z-index: 2;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 100%);
 -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
 transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
.hover14 figure:hover::before {
 -webkit-animation: shine .75s;
 animation: shine .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
 100% {
  left: 125%;
 }
}
@keyframes shine {
 100% {
  left: 125%;
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Vítej v Kasiho světě!</h1>
<p>Má nabídka toho, co umím, zvládám, čemu se věnuji a co chci šířit do světa. Stejně tak chci získávat zkušenosti další i úplně nové. Pojď se tady porozhlédnout a třeba se mi ozveš a navážeme spolupráci.</p>
<br />
<div class="hover14 column">
  <div><a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/o-mne/">
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/o-mne.png" /></figure></a></div> 
<div class="hover14 column">
  <div><a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/trener-parkouru/">
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/parkour.png" /></figure></a></div> <a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/editor-videa/">
<div class="hover14 column">
  <div>
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/videoedit.png" /></figure></a></div> <a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/webmaker/">
<br>
<div class="hover14 column">
  <div>
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/webkamekr.png" /></figure></a></div> <a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/grafika/">
<div class="hover14 column">
  <div>
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/grafika.png"/></figure></a></div> <a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/kontakt/">
<div class="hover14 column">
  <div>
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/kontakt.png" /></figure></a></div>
```

Comment: Could you try replacing each `<div class="hover14 column"><div>` with just `<div class="hover14 column">`? as the inner div seems not to be needed and not to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your HTML with this

```
    <h1>Vítej v Kasiho světě!</h1>
<p>Má nabídka toho, co umím, zvládám, čemu se věnuji a co chci šířit do světa. Stejně tak chci získávat zkušenosti další i úplně nové. Pojď se tady porozhlédnout a třeba se mi ozveš a navážeme spolupráci.</p>


<div class="hover14 column">
  <div><a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/o-mne/">
    <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/o-mne.png" /></figure></a></div>
    <div><a href="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/trener-parkouru/">
      <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/parkour.png" /></figure></a></div>
      <div>
        <figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/videoedit.png" /></figure></a>
      </div>
      <div><figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/webkamekr.png" /></figure></a></div>
      <div><figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/grafika.png"/></figure></a></div>
      <div><figure><img src="http://kasihosvet.g6.cz/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/kontakt.png" /></figure></a></div>
    </div>
```

and css with this

```
body {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

figure {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
figure:hover + span {
  bottom: -36px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Shine */
.hover14 figure {
  position: relative;
}
.hover14 figure::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -75%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%
  );
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
.hover14 figure:hover::before {
  -webkit-animation: shine 0.75s;
  animation: shine 0.75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  100% {
    left: 125%;
  }
}
@keyframes shine {
  100% {
    left: 125%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .column {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

I have used the grid layout with the column, you had way too many divs which almost made it impossible, also some of your links were unclear where they were placed so you may need to add a couple of them in again, but you should now have all 6 images in 2 columns, there is a gap in between them due to the size of the images, you will need to play around with that

Comment: Nice, I really appreciate that and thank you! The problem was mainly in the <div> which was unnecessary, wasn't it? The to be clear, I need it to be optimized for mobile devices as well and now those columns are displayed on the mobile version too where I need them to be below each other. I am sorry, I am a kind of beginner in CSS.

Comment: if you need it for mobile version you need to add in media queries to your CSS -  @media (max-width ...px) and in there specify a size, you usually have to do a few media queries to make it completely responsive and in your media queries you then reset the properties

Comment: I know it is probably not as responsive as it should be, but what about using:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));`
`grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));`

Comment: When you say all below each other do you mean when the size gets smaller, say for mobile everything needs to be in 1 column?

Comment: Yes, totally exactly.

Comment: I've added a media query into the bottom of the CSS in my comment above, it's just underneath your @keyframes, i've set it to 750px but you change that number to the size you want

Comment: Oh, that was that easy, just to add @media  with max-width. Well, now it works as I expected. Very well I thank you once more! :)

Comment: ana no problem, media queries are very handy, you can add as many as you want for different sizes and change your html classes in them... Do you mind to tick my answer to close off the ticket?

Comment: Yup, I will take a look at them closer. And yes, I will tick it. :)